# How to create a redirect rule for 404 pages with many different path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo

Here my problem, the site I'm working on has many 404 pages, but they used to be the same pages with a different path

```
/mens/designers/mens/wales-bonner
/mens/designers/casual-shirts/wales-bonner
/mens/designers/coats-and-jackets/wales-bonner
```

etc.

THe client wants the redirect to go to the category, so

```
/mens/designers/mens/
/mens/designers/casual-shirts/
/mens/designers/coats-and-jackets/
```

I'm pretty sure, there must be a way to have regex rule to cover them all, but I can't seem to find how

Something like
`RewriteRule ^/mens/designers/(.*)/wales-bonner /mens/designers/(.*)`

but it doesn't work, I don't know how to group the middle part of the URL

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several potential problems with your rewrite rule:

1. You have a capturing group in the output URL rather than using `$1` to use the result of the capturing group from the input URL.
2. `^/` won't work in `.htaccess`, only in Apache `.conf` files. I' would use `^/?` instead which will work in either context. That makes the starting slash optional.
3. You don't include an `[R]` flag on the rule to make it a redirect.
4. You don't include an `[L]` flag on the rule to prevent any following rules from interfering with it.

You can also add "mens/designers" to the capturing group so that you don't have to repeat it in the output. I would suggest:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(mens/designers/.*)/wales-bonner /$1 [R=301,L]
```